# how to migrate the existing data to orchard project?,

Tags: migration, orchardcms

there is a company with 16 years information in the database using mySql, now there want to migrate the database to Orchard Project. how to do step by step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, there is 3 ways to do this;

1. Copy and paste the content over. If the site is small, then its faster.
2. Create a specific API where it creates content etc, and then stream the data in from a console app.
3. this is the way I would go.... Export the data from the MySQL DB to a Recipe file, then simply import it.

You will need to understand the format of the recipe file, but once you get that, the rest should be easy.

**Disclosure: I work on Orchard Core**